# Get data from servlet to JSP without forward?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need a double value from my servlet to markup in my JSP. My doGet() is sending back formatted HTML tables with values from an ArrayList, so after I got that working I decided to tackle this part.

Servlet:

//Code getting the tables I need

```
    //Send back the result, this all works good
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(returnAsHTML.toString());
```

What I added to try and get the double value

```
    //Send back the result

    double test = 20;
    request.setAttribute("Test",test);

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(returnAsHTML.toString());

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

In JSP:

```
  <!-- This variable is unresolved -->
  <small>Test : ${Test}</small>
```

The forwarding seems to crash the whole party. I am new to JSP, I'm sure I am missing something small. I need to keep the response.getWriter() stuff there, it gets a lot of the information I need. Now I just don't know how to get my double values I need as well, because they will be displayed on a whole different part of the page.

Comment: Those lines `response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(returnAsHTML.toString());` don't belong in a servlet. They belong in the JSP (which is implicitly already doing that, so you don't need to write all that Java code down at all, just write the HTML down). Put your mouse on top of `[servlets]` tag which you placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link for some sane Hello World examples.

Comment: I'm new to JSP, but without those lines I have no result coming back to the JSP? The returnAsHTML contains all of the information from the servlet that I need to show in my page. So are you implying that I need to move those lines from the doGet() method in my servlet over to my JSP page?

Comment: No. Just put that HTML in `index.jsp` and forward to it. See also the second Hello World example of the servlets wiki page. Any attempts to try to do it differently makes simply no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot *write output to the servletOutputStream*  **and** *redirect* at the same time.

What do you expect from the browser: to display content or to navigate to another page? If the first, don't redirect. If the second, don't display HTML content.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't want to forward at all, but from the research I've done on the matter every example was using forwarding to pass back data to the JSP

Answer (score 0):

Try using httpsession. Encapsulate whatever object you have using session.setAttribiute().
Then forward it using the sendRedirect() method.

**Might be of this kind**

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
double test = 20;
session.setAttribute("Test",test);
response.sendRedirect("Index.jsp");
```

**On the JSP page**

```
String s=(String)session.getAttribite("Test");
double d=Double.parseDouble(s);
```