# Cannot display servlet values in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Long story short, I cannot get my servlet variable to display in my JSP page. I have tried methods like

```
 <p><$= request.getAttribute("foo") %></p>
```

as well as

```
  <p>"${foo}"</p>
```

and importing the page at the top, with and without.

My servlet (commented where the test var is, towards the bottom):

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //String that gets returned as HTML
    StringBuilder returnAsHTML = new StringBuilder();

    //Cycles through the parameter(s) sent from the serialized form
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames;

    //Holds all of the parameter(s) values
    LinkedList<String> valuesIn = new LinkedList<String>();

    //Gets all of the parameter names from the serialized form
    parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

    //Iterate through the enumeration of the parameters
    while(parameterNames.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String currentParameter = parameterNames.nextElement();
        String currentValue = request.getParameter(currentParameter);

        //Prevent a blank value from being added from the text fields (which is what they default to
        //if the user didn't enter anything for "Section:" or "Teacher:").
        if(!currentValue.contentEquals(""))
        {
            valuesIn.add(currentValue);
        }//Else doNothing();
    }

    //Set the section to query, if the user wanted one to search for
    if(request.getParameter("section").isEmpty())
    {
        sectionToQuery = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sectionToQuery = request.getParameter("section").toUpperCase();
    }

    //Set the teacher to query, if the user wanted one to search for
    if(request.getParameter("teacher").isEmpty())
    {
        teacherToQuery = "";
    }
    else
    {
        teacherToQuery = request.getParameter("teacher").toUpperCase();
    }

    //THIS BEGINS THE QUERY - BE SURE TO BREAK THIS DOWN TO OTHER METHODS

    //STAGE 1 See what semesters they are needing, eliminate the ones they don't need.
    resultSet = determineSemesters(valuesIn);

    //STAGE 2 See what locations they are needing, eliminate the ones they don't need.
    determineLocations(resultSet, valuesIn);

    //STAGE 3 See what sections they are needing, eliminate the ones they don't need.
    determineSections(resultSet, valuesIn);

    //STAGE 4 See what instructors they are needing, eliminate the ones they don't need.
    determineInstructors(resultSet, valuesIn);

    //STAGE 5 See if they want to include closed classes or not, eliminate what they don't need.
    determineClosedOrNotClosedCourses(resultSet, valuesIn);

    //SEARCH IS DONE, the remaining elements in "resultSet" are the product of their search. Find
    //The enrollment and the credits that is in resultSet.

    //THIS IS WHERE I AM TESTING IT////////////////
    int foo = 20;
    request.setAttribute("foo", foo);

    //Check to see if the result set is empty
    if(resultSet.isEmpty())
    {
        returnAsHTML.setLength(0);
        returnAsHTML.append("<tr><td colspan='15'><h1>No Results...</h1></tr>");
    }
    else//It's not empty, so style the classes.
    {
        //Make sure results are sorted
        Collections.sort(resultSet);

        //Style all the classes
        for(ClassInfo classes : resultSet)
        {
           returnAsHTML.append(styleClass(classes));
        }//End styling of classes
    }

    //Send back the result
    response.getWriter().write(returnAsHTML.toString());

}
```

Being new to JSP, I have some ideas. In the examples I have seen, it seems that people use response.sendRedirect() or something along those lines with redirecting or forwarding the page. Another is that maybe because I have not casted the int as a String. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are new to Servlets and JSP, this may be helpful to you: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Comment: As I commented in one of your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634842/get-data-from-servlet-to-jsp-without-forward), you keep going in totally the wrong path. That `returnAsHTML` thing belongs in a JSP file which your servlet has to forward to. Please carefully go through a sane JSP/Servlet tutorial to understand the basic concepts. Our tag wiki pages on the subjects are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to redirect your Servlet to appropriate JSP page you should be using [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html), like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/someJsp.jsp"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

To get the value you should use:

```
<p><%= request.getAttribute("foo") %></p>
```

But that is the old and not right way of doing this. You should avoid using scriplets in your JSP page. We have [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) for that purpose. For e.g.:

```
<p>
   <c:out value="${requestScope['foo']}"/>
</p>
```

**See also:**

- [SO Servlets Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Comment: Unfortunately using the RequestDispatcher object will not work. It does successfully send back the request and response, but still the value does not update. Thanks for the help in any event, I will keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your doGet() implementation:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    Object data = "Some data, can be a String or a Javabean";
    request.setAttribute("data", data);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Then in your JSP:

```
<p>The data from servlet: ${data}</p>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input, from my understanding this will throw an IllegalStateException because I sending back a response.getWriter() etc....but if I take that out and just use your code, nothing happens in my page. :-/ The issue is is that I have to send back a string from the servlet to display as HTML which works great, and that's what the response.getWriter().write(returnAsHTML.toString()); is doing. But I also need two int values to display as well.